Django - model images are not loading
I add a ImageField model in my models and save the photos in my project folder. I send the objects to my template but I can't load the images. My app name is observatory and I can have other parts of models except images.
Here is my code :
Models.py :

Class Observatorys (models.Model):

    ...

    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to = "photos/%Y/%m/%d")


Views.py :

From .models import Observatorys



def Observatorys(request):

    Observatorys = observatory.objects.all()

    context= {

       'observatorys': observatorys}

return render(request, 'observatorys/observatorys.html', context)


Urls.py :

urlpatterns = [

path('',views.observatorys,name="observatorys"),

path(,'<int:observatory_id>', views.observatory, name="observatory"),


Template.html :

...

<img src="{{observatory.photo.url}}">

...



Did you add the static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)  to the urls.

I had an typo in urls.py . The second path doesn't have , at the first

Yes I add this but it doesn't work

You add variable 'observatorys' to context, but your template refers to variable 'observatory'. Is this a typo in your question or is it really like this in your code? Does your template refer to value not actually in context? Or do you have some loop by 'observatorys' that isn't shown here?
